# Jquery: find element position from top + element height to activate addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery beginner here.

I'm currently using the below script in order to find an element and then add/remove a class based on the scroll position from said element.

I'm trying to make my fixed navigation icon change colour when over the dark background.

Currently my code says find element 1 and then addClass to element 2 when the user scrolls 1000px after the element is found. It works but isn't ideal as the page is responsive and the sections change height.

You can see here, section 2 is the white section below the top section: http://leebuckle.co.uk/

Id like find the height of section 2 and then add the class once the user scrolls the height of section 2. So it would be +(section_2 height) rather than +1000px

Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var div = $("#section_2");
  var pos = div.position();

$(window).scroll(function () {
  var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (windowpos >= (pos.top + 1000)) {
    $( "#nav-icon span" ).addClass("black_menu");
  }

 else {
    $( "#nav-icon span" ).removeClass("black_menu");
  }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) from jQuery to get the position of an element from the top of the document.

So your line that has

`if (windowpos >= (pos.top + 1000)) { ...`

May look something like:

`if (windowpos >= (div.offset().top)) { ...`

Comment: Thankyou that does exactly what I needed!

I realised that this will only really work for changing the css of a fixed element near the top of the page though.

I'd like to fix my previous and next links too but these are 50% down the page, do you know if there's a way to get 50% the height of the window and use that in the math? So it's basically the same as the code you suggested but with with - 50% of window height in the calculation? Sorry for being such a beginner, out of my depth here :(

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `.offset()` to get the the top position of your section2 + `.height()`, to get your section2's height dynamically.

```
if (windowpos >= (div.offset().top + div.height()))
```